# OUT file getting generated while trying to download a .zip file

Tags: java, unix

I exported a .zip file to a server location(Unix environment), through java.
(eg: 123_abc.zip, which has 123_abc.txt in it)
On verfying the location, appropriate .zip file got created which further has .txt file inside it.

Through java while trying to download same file from that location, header info is passed as "application/zip".
File which gets downloaded is 123_abc.zip, on unzipping it has 123_abc.zip present inside it which is a OUT file. On further unzipping it 123_abc.txt is obtained.

This OUT file which is present in the .zip is not expected.
Please note : this scenario is observed when the application which is doing export/download of .zip file task is deployed inside a portal application. In the absense of portal, my code works fine and OUT file does'nt get created.
(Portal is a application which is menu based and which inturn hosts my application)

Code snippet:

```
    FileInputStream in = 
        new FileInputStream("/opt/xxx/xxx/123_abc.zip");

   response.setContentType("application/zip");

   response.setHeader(Content-Disposition,attachment;filename="123_abc.zip");

    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

     byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    while((length=in.read(bytes)) != -1){
        out.write(bytes, 0, length);
    }
    in.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

Please let me know if anyone has encountered similiar scenario/ What are the reasons that are responsible for OUT file creation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780808/zipoutputstream-working-indifferent-in-local-and-dev-uat-prod-env?rq=1 is similar problem, but it seems, no solutions is provided..

Comment: issue is fixed now.. problem was with response.setContentType("application/zip");
MIME type is taken from servlet Context and hence is set to content type..